# run in multiple containers with same steps

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to have a pipeline where i can run the same steps in different containers?

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  parallel {
    stages {
      stage('Run python-3.11') {
        agent {
          docker 'python:3.11'
        }
        steps {
          sh 'src/main.py'
        }
      }
      stage('Run python-3.12') {
        agent {
          docker 'python:3.12'
        }
        steps {
          sh 'src/main.py'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

like above without repeating the steps

---

Edit: I had already tried it with a `script` block like so:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Parallel') {
      steps {
        script {
          def containers = ['python:3.10', 'python:3.11', 'python:3.12']
          def stages = [:]
          for (def container in containers) {
             stages[container] = generateRun(container)
          }
          parallel stages
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Closure<Void> generateRun(env) {
  return {
    stage('Run') {
      agent {
        docker ${env}
      }
      steps {
        sh 'src/main.py'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this gives me an error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'agent' found among steps`
seems, i can't use agent there?

Comment: I believe this would require using a `script` block for some scripted syntax code using the docker plugin within the declarative. There may be a way to completely code this with declarative syntax though.

Comment: I had already tried that, adding it to question